# Current menu item - foreach

Tags: php

Consider this:

```
    $menuItems = array (
        "page1" => "1.php",
        "page2" => "2.php",
        "page3" => "3.php",
        "page4" => "4.php",
        "page5" => "5.php",
     );
```

and now I create the menu like this:

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <?php 
           foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {
           echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
           } 
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Works great. But now I need to add a class .current on the current page.

To get the current page I do this:

```
      <?php 
         function curPageName() {
            return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
         }
         $curpage = curPageName();
      ?>
```

And it also works great.

SO I guess the question is how do I assign $curpage to the ... current page? :)

Thank you.
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Easy, inside your loop, check if `$url == $curpage`, and append appropriately.

Example:

```
<?php

    $menuItems    = array(
        "page1" => "1.php",
        "page2" => "2.php",
        "page3" => "3.php",
        "page4" => "4.php",
        "page5" => "5.php",
    );
    $current_item = "2.php"; //Assume we got this from the function
?>
<ul class="menu">
    <?php
    foreach ($menuItems as $name => $url) {
        echo "<li><a href='$url'";
        if ($url == $current_item) {
            echo " class='current'";
        }
        echo ">$name</a></li>\n";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well - easy would be if I would be a programmer but i'm a total newbie. Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: I tried this: 'foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {
     if ($url == $curtitle)
     echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";'

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ul class="menu">
    <?php 
       foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {

       if ($url === $curpage){
          $class.=' .current';
       }

       echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";

       } 
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: this solution displays ALL menu items as current... :(

Comment: you get current url correctly ? if all urls checked as current => all urls are same and equal current url

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="menu">
    <?php 
       foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {
       $class = 'default';
       if (curPageName() == $name) {
          $class.='.current';
       } 
       echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
       } 
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Certainly not, because $menuItems is associated array.

Comment: foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {
       $class = 'default';
       if (curPageName() == $url) {
          $class.=' \. current';
       } 
       echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
       }  - LIKE THIS WORKS :)

Answer (score 0):

So I made it work with your help! Thanks guys.
Special thanks for Adel - although you had a mistake there I fixed it like this:

```
    foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {
          $class = 'default';
          if (curPageName() == $url) {
             $class.=' \. current';
          } 
         echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
         }
```

Awesome! Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at the html: <a class="default \. current" href="galeria.php">galeria</a> - doesnt look good but it works :)

Comment: had to erase the dot: $class.=' current';

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $menuItems = array(
               'page1' => '1.php',
               'page2' => '2.php',
               'page3' => '3.php',
               'page4' => '4.php',
               'page5' => '5.php',
  );
  $current_page = curPageName();
?>
<ul class="menu">
  <?php
    foreach ($menuItems as $name => $url) {
  ?>
    <li><a href="<?php=$url?>"
    <?php 
      if ($url == $current_page) {
    ?>
    class="current"
    <?php 
      } 
    ?>
    ><?php=$name?></a></li>
  <?php 
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Why use the curPageName () at each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary syntax to solve your problem. It consists in this syntax:

```
(if condition ? true : false)
```

So we can use this way on your answer comparing the `curPageName` with the `url` inside the foreach loop.

```
$url == curPageName() ? 'current' : 'notCurrent'
```

Now you just need to use this in your favor.

I like the syntax of **printf**. So the code is more clean. Try this:

```
<?php
/**
 * curPageName()  is defined in question
 * my_links() is a shortcut to array defined in question
 */
$template = "<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>";
$links    = my_links();
$current  = curPageName();
print '<ul class="menu">';
foreach ($likns as $name => $url) {
  $class = $current == $url ? ' class="current"' : '';
  printf($template, $class, $url, $name);
}
print '</ul>';
```

Each `%s` item in `$template` will be changed by sequential variable. So, if you need to change the template the code is clean and easyest to give a maintance.

Or, if you want another easiest template way, use the php template syntax. Note the use of `:` after the foreach statement and the use of `endforeach`. You can see that I am using the short code of echo `<?=$var?>` that is more compreensible than `<?php echo $var ?>`.

```
<?php
/**
 * curPageName()  is defined in question
 * my_links() is a shortcut to array defined in question
 */
$links   = my_links();
$current = curPageName();
?>
<ul class="menu">
  <?php foreach ($links as $name => $url): ?>
    <li<?=($current == $url ? ' class="current"' : '')?>>
        <a href="<?=$url?>"><?=$name?></a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ow, based on @kirill-speransky 's great [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703903/current-menu-item-foreach/11704347#11704347), you really do not have to use the curPageName() on each `foreach` interaction. It forces the machinne to work. Learn this!